# Doctrine OneToOne relation bidirectional

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-3.4

I'm facing an issue concerning OneToOne relation between some Entities.
The subtlety is that the owner side can be multiple classes (all children of the same class).

#### Here is the summary

I've got `Process` which have several children entity classes (let's take `ProcessPassport`, `ProcessIdentityCard` and `ProcessCadaster` for example)

Some of my children entities need a relation with another entity `TaxStamp`, but not all of them. So I cannot put this association in the `Process` main entity.
Instead I created a trait `TaxStampTrait`, containing my relation mapping.

But this does not work properly :

1. I cannot define multiple possibilities for the association on the `TaxStamp` entity
2. Doctrine tells me there are error in my annotations for the relation, because I refer to the `Process` (legit since only some entities use the `TaxStampTrait`)

Question: what should I do to make it all work the right way?

Here is the gist with a summary of the code and classes:  https://gist.github.com/bastos71/8e15f69ebecf5e97dc75187d130fe109

```
<?php

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="ProcessRepository")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 */
class Process
{
    // ...
}
```

---

```
<?php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="ProcessCadasterRepository")
 */
class ProcessCadaster extends Process implements EntityWithTaxStampInterface
{
  use TaxStampTrait;
  // ...
}
```

---

```
<?php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="ProcessIdentityCardRepository")
 */
class ProcessIdentityCard extends Process implements EntityWithTaxStampInterface
{
  use TaxStampTrait;
  // ...
}
```

---

```
<?php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="ProcessPassportRepository")
 */
class ProcessPassport extends Process implements EntityWithTaxStampInterface
{
  use TaxStampTrait;
  // ...
}
```

---

```
<?php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="TaxStampRepository")
 */
class TaxStamp
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Advercity\AdminBundle\Entity\Process", mappedBy="taxStamp")
     */
    private $process;

    // ...
}
```

---

```
<?php
trait TaxStampTrait
{
  /**
   * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="TaxStamp", cascade={"persist"})
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="tax_stamp_id", referencedColumnName="id")
   */
  private $taxStamp;
  
  // ...
}
```